# Jooq Global Artefacts Rename

Tags: java, jooq

Jooq code generator creates some global artefacts in a specified directory which are great. But is there a way to add some prefix / suffix on them so the names wont collide with the actual entities?

I have been reading [this](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.13/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-generate/codegen-generate-globals/) but without any hope :/

What I have is a package "entity" with an item called "Event" inside. The code generator will create an "Event" global artefact which requires the fully qualified name to be called if I have already imported the Event in my class. I would like to avoid that by added a prefix on the generated Item, something like what queryDsl does with the Q as prefix.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use generator strategies ([programmatic](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-generatorstrategy/) or [configurative](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-matcherstrategy/)) to influence the generated names of objects.

Comment: The problem is not the package but the actual name. Lets say I have a table "Event" within some X package. the jooq generator will create an "Event" global artefact in some Y package. So if I write a jooq query to fetch all events from the table I will require dsl.selectFrom(Event.EVENT).fetchStreamInto(X<package>.Event.class) to store them in my object to pass it around. Also I will try the generator strategies as they may be the solution.

Comment: @MichaelMichailidis: OK, I misread your question, so the first part didn't apply...

Comment: Yes did it work with the programmatic just fine! just because the project is single-module I had to add an extra compilation step in my maven config ( Suggestion to include in the docs also ) to compile the programmatic config first so the generator will be able to pick it up